# GRUB error- no suitable video mode found

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-loader, lfs

I recently made an LFS and made some changes in GRUB. I added the update-grub command. I'm able to set background color and highlight color. But when I add a custom theme-
 `update-grub` gives-

> Generating grub configuration file ...
>   
> Found theme: /boot/grub/theme/dark_squares/theme.txt
>   
> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz
>   
> Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-no-kmods
>   
> done

Looks good. Doesn't it?

However, when I reboot, some error flashes by too fast, but it boots normally. However, I managed to ( don't ask how) read the errors-

> error: file `/boot/grub/fonts/unicode.pf2` not found.
>   
> error: no suitable video mode found

this is my `/etc/default/grub`-

```
# If you change this file, run grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
# afterwards to update /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_SAVE_DEFAULT="true"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="false"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Papiya`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_THEME=/boot/grub/theme/dark_squares/theme.txt
# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
# Select the terminal output device. You may select multiple devices                 here,
# separated by spaces.
# Valid terminal output names depend on the platform, but may include ‘console’
# (PC BIOS and EFI consoles), ‘serial’ (serial terminal), ‘gfxterm’     (graphics-mode
# output), ‘ofconsole’ (Open Firmware console), or ‘vga_text’ (VGA text output,
# mainly useful with Coreboot).
# The default is to use the platform's native terminal output. 
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="gfxterm"
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE="1024x768x32"
# If graphical video support is required, either because the ‘gfxterm’ graphical
# terminal is in use or because ‘GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX’ is set, then grub-mkconfig
# will normally load all available GRUB video drivers and use the one most
# appropriate for your hardware. If you need to override this for some reason,
# then you can set this option. After grub-install has been run, the available
# video drivers are listed in /boot/grub/video.lst. 
GRUB_VIDEO_BACKEND="vbe"
# Uncomment to select a font to use
#GRUB_FONT_PATH="/boot/grub/DejaVuSansMono.pf2"
# Set a background image for use with the ‘gfxterm’ graphical terminal. The value
# of this option must be a file readable by GRUB at boot time, and it must end
# with .png, .tga, .jpg, or .jpeg. The image will be scaled if necessary to fit
# the screen.
#GRUB_BACKGROUND="/usr/share/grub_backgrounds/magnetar_1024x768.jpg"
# Set to ‘text’ to force the Linux kernel to boot in normal text mode, ‘keep’ to
# preserve the graphics mode set using ‘GRUB_GFXMODE’, ‘widthxheight’[‘xdepth’] to
# set a particular graphics mode, or a sequence of these separated by commas or
# semicolons to try several modes in sequence. See gfxpayload.
#
# Depending on your kernel, your distribution, your graphics card, and the phase of
# the moon, note that using this option may cause GNU/Linux to suffer from various 
# display problems, particularly during the early part of the boot sequence. If you
# have problems, set this option to ‘text’ and GRUB will tell Linux to boot in
# normal text mode. 
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="keep"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entrys
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"
# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Solved this by copying `unicode.pf2` file to `/boot/grub/fonts`.

[Source](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=630998)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to boot using GRUB command line (without `grub.cfg` file), so I had to load the video module to get my TinyCore to boot:

`insmod all_video`

Without this, I was getting the same error as OP.

However, as **Aniket Bhattacharyea** answered, I also did have to manually copy `unicode.pf2` file to `/boot/grub/fonts` to get `terminal_output gfxterm` to output valid characters.